# What is it called when a violinist quickly bows all strings in an 'arpeggio-like' flourish?

Tags: technique, terminology, violin

You can hear this 'arpeggiating' flourish in *Heifetz's 'Last Recital'* during Strauss's *Sonata for Violin & Piano* [here](https://youtu.be/yrL9bhhewgw?t=2747) (already cued to 45:48) and (in case you prefer animated movie soundtracks over Strauss) in the *Coraline Sountrack* very briefly [here](https://youtu.be/rkNQJqi90fA?t=917) (already cued to 15:22).

What is the term for this — *is* there a term for this?

Comment: It's just two arpeggios back to back - one up and one down.?

Comment: Arpeggios. Covering a full octave, if you want to say more. They are repeated; and they are slurred.

Comment: The OP is clearly looking for or wondering if there is a more precise word than "arpeggio" for this particular technique, since the word "arpeggiating" appears in the question.

Comment: Not posting as an answer because I'm really not sure, but I don't believe there is a more specific term. The most famous example of this I can think of is probably this section of the Bach Chaconne, which I've only ever heard referred to as "the arpeggio section": https://youtu.be/1zvRWFD_1_M?t=322 Cued, but listen to it from the start anyway, you know you want to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the term you are looking for is "bariolage." It is often used to describe passages that alternate between two strings—one open and the other mostly stopped (often playing a melody that is meant to be heard apart from the open-string pedal or cover tone)—but can also be extended to passages involving more strings. There are some good examples at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bariolage. As a string player, I *love* this technique when it's done well, because it is usually not nearly as difficult to play as it sounds, and I can really dig into it. As a composer, I like the technique because I can very quickly create a more complex texture to surround my harmonic or melodic ideas. One of my favorite 20th-century examples is the beginning of the second movement of Alfred Schnittke's second string quartet.

Comment: That's absolutely it. I'd never have found this without you, and now I've been introduced to Schnittke! Thanks for both :)